# Instability in second order ODE in Julia

Tags: julia, differential-equations

I want to solve numerically a second-order ODE (see first equation below) which depends on relatively easy functions (g, g'/g and f/g are superpositions of cos,sine,cosh,sinh). The main problem is that these functions depend on a function alpha (e.g. cos(alpha*phi)), and only its derivative is known (see second equation below, sigma and d are fixed).

[image: eqdiff]

This is obviously difficult to solve, so I tried first something simpler, setting alpha=phi². My code returns the warning `Warning: Automatic dt set the starting dt as NaN, causing instability.` followed by `Warning: NaN dt detected. Likely a NaN value in the state, parameters, or derivative value caused this outcome.` The code runs, but plotting the solution gives an error `ArgumentError: reducing over an empty collection is not allowed`, which I assume is telling me my solution is empty.

I have found a [post](https://discourse.julialang.org/t/integration-fails-warning-automatic-dt-set-the-starting-dt-as-nan-causing-instability/56030) with a similar issue, in which the error occurred because the parameters were giving a divergent solution, but in my case all the functions in the ODE are well-defined on the interval of interest (-5,5), so I doubt this would be my case. I have three questions then:

1. **How can I know where is the NaN value exactly?**
2. **How can I avoid this error?**
3. **Is there a way to implement the full expression (d alpha/d phi) into an integrator?**

Many thanks!

EDIT: Following the comment of @Lutz Lehmann, I tried to reduce the 2nd order ODE and solve the three equations simultaneously, but Julia tells me  `UndefVarError: α not defined`, even though I explicitly define it as the third equation. What am I doing wrong?

EDIT2: The error disappeared after renaming the functions correctly. However, I receive the same warnings and error as before, with the addition of `Warning: First function call produced NaNs. Exiting.` in first instance.

EDIT3: I have now written the expression for dα is a simpler way, and corrected two mistakes in the code (sign pointed out by @Lutz Lehmann and a missing closing parenthesis). After giving a small non-zero initial value to α and A', I can see the solution blows up at time ϕ>2.12, so I guess the problem lies there.

EDIT4: I am now closer to the source of the problem, but I don't know how to proceed further. I have tried to see which terms are problematic in the equation for dα/dϕ, and it seems the instability arises for the sinh and cosh terms. For example, trying to solve `dα/dϕ = 2d*sinh(s2*α*ϕ)` upsets the solver immediately, which returns `Warning: Instability detected. Aborting`. But Julia should be able to solve this, so what am I missing?

[image]

```
using DifferentialEquations
using Plots

const global lp=1.               
const global s2=81.
const global  d=-9.0e-4
const global B=1.    # Parameter in the gaussian f(\phi) defined below
const global β =1.   # Parameter in the gaussian f(\phi) defined below
const global k=1.    # Wave number           

@variables α,ϕ

# Useful functions
#α(ϕ) = ϕ^2 
 
g1(α,ϕ) = s2^2*α^2*sinh(s2*α*ϕ)*sin(2d*α)
g2(α,ϕ) = cos(2d*α)+cosh(s2*α*ϕ)
g3(α,ϕ) = -α*s2*sin(2d*α)+2d*cos(2d*α)+2d*cosh(s2*α*ϕ)
g(α,ϕ) = exp(-2α)*g3(α,ϕ)/g2(α,ϕ)/2/lp
dgg(α,ϕ) = g1(α,ϕ)/g2(α,ϕ)/g3(α,ϕ) # Derivative of g over g

f1(α,ϕ) = -4B*lp*exp(2α)*ϕ*exp(-ϕ^2/β^2)/β^2
f2(α,ϕ) = cos(2d*α)+cosh(s2*α*ϕ)
f3(α,ϕ) = -α*s2*sin(2d*α)+2d*cos(2d*α)+2d*cosh(s2*α*ϕ)
dfg(α,ϕ) = f1(α,ϕ)*f2(α,ϕ)/f3(α,ϕ) # Derivative of f over g

α1(α,ϕ) = ϕ*s2*sin(2d*α)+2d*sinh(s2*α*ϕ)

function eom(du,u,p,ϕ)
    α = u[1]
    A = u[2]
    dA = u[3]
    du[1] = α1(α,ϕ)/g3(α,ϕ)
    du[2] = dA
    du[3] = -2*dgg(α,ϕ)*dA-2*dfg(α,ϕ)*dA-k^2*A/g(α,ϕ)
end 
A₀ = [0.1,0.,0.1]               # initial state vector
tspan = (-5.0,5.0)                  # time interval
prob = ODEProblem(eom,A₀,tspan)
sol = solve(prob,Tsit5())
plot(sol)

# Full solution to implement in the future
# dαdϕ1(ϕ) = ϕ*s2*sin(2d*α)+2d*sinh(s2*α*ϕ)
# dαdϕ(ϕ) = dαdϕ1(ϕ)/g3(ϕ) 

# Original problem
# function eom(ddu,du,u,p,ϕ)
#     ddu[1] = -2dgg(ϕ)*du[1]-2dfg(ϕ)*du[1]-k^2*u[1]/g(ϕ)
# end
# u0 = [0.]                  # initial state vector
# du0 = [0.]
# tspan = (-5.0,5.0)                  # time interval
# prob = SecondOrderODEProblem(eom,du0,u0,tspan)
# sol = solve(prob,Tsit5())
# plot(sol)
```

Comment: Why not solve the alpha equation along with the equation for A? Make a first-order system for the 3 components and use a general IVP solver.

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by "the 3 components". Are you saying I should break the second order ODE into first-order equations?

Comment: Yes, exactly that. You automatically get the correct values of α, no need to make any further assumptions. (Keep on using α instead of u[3] to be closer to the formulas) ((code-in-text markup is with single quotes, the triple quote code fences only work for paragraphs. I believe they do not work in comments.))

Comment: I have tried this but I fail to define α inside the function. I have edited my post with my attempt.

Comment: This is for inside the `g` functions. These should all be `g(α,ϕ)`, and then replace all `α(ϕ)` by `α`. The other strategy would be to solve the third equation separately with dense output, and then use the dense output interpolation function to get the values of `α(ϕ)`.

Comment: This indeed helped! But I now have the same kind of error I was having at the beginning with alpha arbitrary defined.

Comment: Sign error in `du[2]`, there should be no plus sign. Could you compute the result of the ODE function at the initial point and see if there are any irregularities there?

Comment: Thanks for the plus sign. I have also corrected another mistake, and the code runs. The output doesn't make sense though, as I explain in EDIT3.